# Parse Ethereum private key in string in Go

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am trying really hard to convert Ethereum private keys BIP44 in string format to a type that can (*ecdsa.PrivateKey) be used by rest of the code.

```
import (
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)

const (
    privateKey2 string = "0xbacd06016aea4280e14efd7182ba18cd98bf11701943d3d47d76b04bb7baad19"
)

func main() {
    _, err = x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(firstKey)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot parse private key")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how a private key can be converted to Ethereum address
You need to import one additional package "crypto/ecdsa" and also remove "0x" from the private key.

```
    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(privateKey2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    publicKey := privateKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, ok := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("error casting public key to ECDSA")
    }

    fromAddress := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA)
```